# To Mock a Mockingbird Flower Garden in Prolog

Tags: prolog

So I'm trying to solve the 1st problem in the famous book "To Mock A Mockingbird".
It's called "Flower garden" and is defined as:

> In a certain flower garden, each flower was either red, yellow, or blue, and all three colours were represented. A statistician once visited the garden and made the observation that whatever three flowers you picked, at least one of them was bound to be red. A second statistician visited the garden and made the observation that whatever three flowers you picked, at least one was bound to be yellow. Two logic students heard about this and got into an argument. The first student said: "It therefore follows that whatever three flowers you pick, at least one is bound to be blue, doesn't it?" The second student said: "Of course not!"
>
> Which student was right, and why?

So the solution is quite simple if you think about it, but what would it take for a program to solve it?

(You can find the solution on P.19 in the book: http://www.scribd.com/doc/194863914/Raymond-M-Smullyan-To-Mock-a-Mockingbird-and-Other-Logic-Puzzles-Including-an-Amazing-Adventure-in-Combinatory-Logic-Knopf-1985)

I thought Prolog might be the right choice of language, since,  well, it's to do with logic programming...
Though I have some inferences set up, that should give me the solution, but I'm kind of stuck, because the program doesn't finish properly.

Here is what I have so far, have you got any suggestions as to what I'm missing/doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/env swipl -q -g main -s

subsets_contain_item(_, []).
subsets_contain_item(Item, [H|T]) :-
    member(Item, H), subsets_contain_item(Item, T).

subsets_length([], _).
subsets_length([H|T], Len) :-
    length(H, Len), subsets_length(T, Len).

all_are_members_and_only(Items, L) :-
    all_are_members(Items, L),
    only_members(Items, L).

all_are_members([], _).
all_are_members([M|T], L) :-
    member(M, L), all_are_members(T, L).

only_members(_, []).
only_members(Items, [H|T]) :-
    member(H, Items), only_members(Items, T).

main(_) :-
    all_are_members_and_only([red, yellow, blue], Solution),
    subsets_contain_item(red, L),
    subsets_contain_item(yellow, L),
    findall(X0, only_members(Solution, X0), L),
    length(X0, 3),
    write(Solution).
```

Comment: The `length(X0, 3)` looks out of place. Did you mean for it to be inside your `findall/3`?

Comment: Where would you suggest putting the length restriction? I thought about using `subsets_length/2` too, but they both have the same effect.

Comment: `X0` is a variable inside of `findall`, so the reference in `length(X0, 3)` is out of place. Maybe you wanted, `findall(X0, (only_members(Solution, X0), length(X0, 3)), L)` which will capture in `L` those elements `X0` with length of `3`.

Answer (score 1):

Completely different approach - constraint logic programming using ECLiPSe CLP Prolog http://www.eclipseclp.org/ (can be translated to other Prologs).

```
:- lib(ic).
:- lib(ic_global).

model(N, Flowers) :-
    dim(Flowers, [N]),
    Flowers :: 1..3, % 1 - Red, 2 - Yellow, 3 - Blue

    %  all three colours were represented
    atleast(1, Flowers, 1), atleast(1, Flowers, 2), atleast(1, Flowers, 3), 

    ( multifor([I, J, K], 1, N), param(Flowers) do
        ( (I =:= J ; I =:= K; J =:= K) ->
            % skip for non-different flowers
            true
        ;
            % at least one of them was bound to be red
            Flowers[I] #= 1 or Flowers[J] #= 1 or Flowers[K] #= 1,
            %  at least one was bound to be yellow
            Flowers[I] #= 2 or Flowers[J] #= 2 or Flowers[K] #= 2
        )
    ).
```

After we have our model we can, for example, ask to give us all possible configurations for 3-flower garden:

```
[eclipse]: findall(Flowers, (model(3, Flowers), labeling(Flowers)), Sols).

Flowers = Flowers
Sols = [[](1, 2, 3), [](1, 3, 2), [](2, 1, 3), [](2, 3, 1), [](3, 1, 2), [](3, 2, 1)]
```

All found configurations are just permutations of 1, 2, 3 - one red, one yellow and one blue flower. (we can add so-called symmetry-breaking constraints to our model to have only [](1, 2, 3) without permutations).

Now let's try larger garden sizes:

```
[eclipse]: findall(Flowers, (model(4, Flowers), labeling(Flowers)), Sols).
Flowers = Flowers
Sols = []

[eclipse]: findall(Flowers, (model(5, Flowers), labeling(Flowers)), Sols).
Flowers = Flowers
Sols = []
```

There are no solutions for sizes 4 and 5. We can try even bigger numbers - no solutions, so we can conjecture with high degree of confidence (although we haven't proved it) that the only solution is the garden of size 3 with one red, one yellow, and one blue flower. The first student was right.

Comment: This going to get me crazy. There is nothing in the original puzzle that says the garden contains three flowers only. I can't find the logic to deduce that from the statisticians reports ?

Comment: @Sniffer yes, nothing says that the garden contains 3 flowers. I tried 3, 4, 5, and some more: only 3 worked. It's not a proof, of course.

Comment: The actual solution ( the one proposed by the author) can be found via Google. The thing is I don't find the reasoning reasonable. I will post a link later if you could've find the answer. Thank you